# using js-cookie, any search term with a slash is adding '52' to search term

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

i am using [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/blob/master/src/js.cookie.js) to store cookies on site. i have a search input field that is storing the input as a variable, and then removing any slash before it is saved. the following code works great:

```
data.searchTerm = $(el).closest('label').find('input').first().val();
var term = encodeURIComponent(data.searchTerm);
        term = term.replace('%2F','%252F');//allow slash in search field
        this.searchTerm = term;
```

the problem is when i search for something that has a slash in the search term - say 'theme/layout' - when i view the `term` variable in console i see the correct output of the search term with the correct slash replacement:

`theme%252Flayout`

and if you put that into my search query it works great. but when i use the following code to store it as a cookie:

```
Cookies.set("MYSEARCHTERM", this.searchTerm, {expires:5});
```

the cookie result is returned as:

```
theme%25252Flayout
```

if you compare that to the actual search term using encodeURI and .replace, i get the following:

```
theme%252Flayout
```

so as a result of this, the cookie is adding '52' to the value in the cookie. when i test with normal search terms that do not have a slash in the term, it works fine. yet when i use search terms with a slash, this is when the cookie stores the value incorrectly. i am reaching out to see if any one sees something i am missing here, or ran into this problem with js-cookie in the past?

Answer (score 0):

check to make sure the variable is not being double encoded